# Custom Preference with a StringSet

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have a list of folders I'd like to display in a preference as a list of strings.  I'm storing the folders via `SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet()`. The user can click a row to remove that entry.

I'm not sure how to display the values in a custom `Preference`; a ListView would be ideal.  The built in preferences don't support this use case and `Preference.getPersistedStringSet` is hidden "pending API approval", apparently for years, so a custom Preference won't work easily.

I could use a delimited string with a static helper method within the custom `Preference` to ensure a call to `SharedPreferences.Editor.putString()` (instead of `putStringSet`) is formatted properly, but that's a bit sloppy.  Any better ideas?

Comment: "I have a list of folders I'd like to display in a preference" -- what does this mean? Do you mean that you want to use a `ListPreference` or `MultiSelectListPreference` to collect values from the user? "I don't know how to display the values in a preference" -- what does this mean? Do you want to show them in a `TextView`? A `ListView`? A `Spinner`? A `RecyclerView`? An OpenGL-based top-down shooter game? Something else?

Comment: lol, yah that was a little too terse reading it, sorry, edited.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to display the values in a custom Preference; a ListView would be ideal" -- OK, what's wrong with a `ListPreference`? Call `setEntries()` and `setEntryValues()` with your roster of folders, where you retrieve those via `getStringSet()` and convert to the `CharSequence[]` needed by `ListPreference`.

Comment: Yah that makes sense.  Realizing I couldn't 'key' the string set to the ListPreference, I overlooked the simple solution.  I'll follow up when I have it working.

Comment: Actually the concept of a single "selection" in a `ListPreference` is a bit misleading in this case.  No entry exists in prominence.  The setting exists solely to remove folder listings when necessary, like a monitored folder dialog with only delete.  I think a custom `ListView` preference with the `setEntries` like you mentioned is the way to go.  It won't encapsulate any of the preference logic, but it won't be as ghetto as using a delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created a custom `DialogPreference` as the existing views would have been a poor/confusing user experience.  It will actually link to (and requires) a `StringSet` preference key and allow the user to remove entries.  You could modify the `onClick` to have it behave differently.

```
public class RemovableListPreference extends DialogPreference implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final String androidns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    private TextView mSplashText,mValueText;
    private String mPreferenceKey;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage;

    public RemovableListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context,attrs);
        mContext = context;

        // Message attribute for the alert dialog
        int mDialogMessageId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "dialogMessage", 0);
        if(mDialogMessageId == 0)
            mDialogMessage = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "dialogMessage");
        else
            mDialogMessage = mContext.getString(mDialogMessageId);

        // Key attribute for the view, used to automatically update the preferences
        int preferenceId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "key", -1);
        if (preferenceId == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException(RemovableListPreference.class.getSimpleName() + " requires a preference key (android:key)");
        else
            mPreferenceKey = mContext.getString(preferenceId);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6,6,6,6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);

        mListView = new ListView(mContext);
        mListView.setDivider(getDivider());

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
            }
        });
        layout.addView(mListView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setEntries(Set<String> entries)
    {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(entries);
    }

    @Override
    public void showDialog(Bundle state) {

        super.showDialog(state);

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        Set<String> excludedFolders = pref.getStringSet(mContext.getString(R.string.KEY_EXCLUDED_FOLDERS), new HashSet<String>());
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(excludedFolders);

        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mPreferenceKey != null)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).edit();
            Set<String> rows = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); ++i)
            {
                rows.add(mAdapter.getItem(i));
            }
            editor.putStringSet(mPreferenceKey, rows);
            editor.apply();
        }
        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).dismiss();
    }

    private Drawable getDivider() {
        int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.listDivider };
        TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        Drawable divider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();

        return divider;
    }
}
```

Ex. header:

```
<com.anthonymandra.widget.RemovableListPreference
    android:key="@string/KEY_EXCLUDED_FOLDERS"
    android:negativeButtonText=""
    android:title="@string/excludedFolders"
    android:summary="@string/excludedSummary"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/excludedFolders"
    android:dialogMessage="@string/excludedMessage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of saving a set of strings:

```
SharedPreferences sp = SharedPreferences.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

//Save the values
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfFolders);
editor.putStringSet("key", set);
editor.commit();

//Get the values
Set<String> set = sp.getStringSet("key", null);
```

I hope this works for you.

**Edit:**

You can also use a ListPreference with a set of entries and entries values. You can change these entries anytime programmatically like:

```
listPref.setEntries(R.array.listArray);
listPref.setEntryValues(R.array.listValues);
```

You can also persist the data like:

```
listPref.setPersistent(true);
```

More Info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html

Comment: Thanks, that part I have in place.  It's a matter of displaying the string set which seems to have been left as an oversight in the `Preference` class.

Comment: @Anthony Oh, so you want to make a custom preference in your preference screen to display a string array or what? If yes, tell me. That's very simple. Sorry for misunderstanding. :)

Comment: Yes, just a series of string paths that can be clicked.  I think I'll just extend `DialogPreference` with a `ListView`

Comment: Why not use a ListPreference? It is the same as what you want to achieve.

Comment: No a list preference has a selected item which make no sense in this case.